# Change behavior of buttons in datarepeater

Tags: c#, forms, datarepeater

So I have this application where I'm trying to create a notification `panel` which will display some data (which will be handled by a `datasource` based on an `object`) in a `datarepeater`. However some of these notifications need to behave different than others. For example a missed message notification needs 3 `buttons` (ignore,respond,delete) while a software version notification would only need 2 (ignore,delete). Is there any way to do this with the `datarepeater` or should I just create a different `datasource` and `datarepeater` for each type of notification

Comment: show some stuff(code snippet) as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have a data repeater and use the data binding event `(Button1_DataBinding)` and then use:

```
((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent)
```

to get to the `gridview` row, you can then expand that to look at the datarow in question:

`((DataRowView)((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent).DataItem)`["FIELD1"]

I can then set the visible property for the button based on any field or combination of from the bound data, example:

```
DataRowView DRV = (DataRowView)((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent).DataItem;

if (DRV["FIELD1"].ToString().Trim() == "1234567")

((Button)sender).Visible = false;

 else ((Button)sender).Visible = true;
```

sure there is a more efficient way but it works